# Why do we write pressure as $\frac{F\cos\theta}{A}$, and not $\frac{F}{A\cos\theta}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure, vectors, fluid-statics

[image]

If you can follow from the diagram, the latter should be equally correct.

Answer (score 5):

In your proposed equation, when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, then you would have infinite pressure, which doesn't make sense.

If the force is parallel to the surface then there would be no pressure. This is why you typically see pressure written as

$$P=\frac{F_{\bot}}{A}$$

where $F_{\bot}$ is the component of the force perpendicular to the surface. Based on your diagram, $F_{\bot}=F\cos\theta$, and $F_{\bot}\neq\frac{F}{\cos\theta}$